# Setting string a variable to get values from a structured array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, structure

I have a simple problem in VB.net.
I want to retrieve datas from an array declared as structure using a string to visualize the variable.
Below my code:

```
Module DataAnalisys

Dim InputData(100000) As InputDataStructure
Dim VariablesParameter(6) As VariablesParameterStructure
Dim VariablesGlobal(6) As VariablesDataStrucutre

Structure InputDataStructure
    Dim ID As Integer
    Dim FileId As Integer
    Dim ProductionDate As Date
    Dim ProductionTime As Date
    Dim Shift As Integer
    Dim IPP As Integer
    Dim BPS As Integer
    Dim SerialNumber As String
    Dim Top As Single
    Dim Bottom As Single
    Dim Right As Single
    Dim Left As Single
    Dim OffCutH As Single
    Dim OffCutV As Single
    Dim Row As Byte
    Dim Col As String
    Dim Position As String
    Dim Pack As Integer
    Dim Sheet As Integer
    Dim SheetInPack As Integer
End Structure

Structure VariablesParameterStructure
    Dim NameParameter As String
    Dim Target As Single
    Dim Tolerance As Single
    Dim LowTolerance As Single
    Dim UppTolerance As Single
End Structure

Structure VariablesDataStrucutre
    Dim NameData As String
    Dim Position As String
    Dim N As Long
    Dim Mean As Single
    Dim Difference As Single
    Dim Scrap As Single
    Dim ScrapGreat As Single
    Dim ScrapLess As Single
    Dim SeMean As Single
    Dim StDev As Single
    Dim Min As Single
    Dim Q1 As Single
    Dim Median As Single
    Dim Q3 As Single
    Dim Max As Single
End Structure

Sub RoutineAnalisysGlobal()

    For B As Byte = 0 To VariablesGlobal.Length - 1

        Dim ID As String = VariablesParameter(B).NameParameter
        Dim Target As Single = VariablesParameter(B).Target
        Dim LowTol As Single = VariablesParameter(B).LowTolerance
        Dim UppTol As Single = VariablesParameter(B).UppTolerance

        With VariablesGlobal(B)
            .NameData = ID
            .Position = "All"
            .N = InputData.Length
            .Mean = InputData.Average(Function(f) f.ID)
            .Difference = .Mean - Target
            .ScrapLess = InputData.Count(Function(f) f.ID < LowTol)
            .ScrapGreat = InputData.Count(Function(f) f.ID > UppTol)
            .Q1 = InputData.FirstQuartile(Function(F) F.ID)
            .Min = InputData.Min(Function(f) f.ID)
            .Median = InputdataMedian(Function(f) f.ID)
            .Q3 = InputData.ThirdQuartile(Function(f) f.ID)
            .Max = InputData.Max(Function(f) f.ID)
        End With
    Next

End Sub

End Module
```

The VariablesParameter().Name are Top, Bottom, Right, Left, OffCutH and OffCutV.

The code does not work when I'm using the part (Function(f) f.ID) as I want to use the function on different items of the structure of InputData according the for cycle. I want to display f.Top f.Bottom f.Right f.Left f.OffCutH and f.OffCutV.

Does anyone want to help me? I was looking on how convert the string ID into the variable of InputData.?????? structure.

Comment: What exactly is this supposed to do: `.Mean = InputData.Average(Function(f) f.ID)`? As it stands, you're getting the average of all the `ID` values, which doesn't seem to make sense. I suspect what you actually want is to get the average of some other field for all elements where the `ID` is equal to some specific value. Is that correct? If so then you need to call `Where` first, to filter the data, then call `Average` and specify the field you want to get the average of, e.g. `.Mean = InputData.Where(Function(f) f.ID = ID).Average(Function(f) f.Top)`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney maybe ID is misleading as it is present two times in the code. I want to do a really simple stuff for example just the following 6 averages: `InputData.Average(Function(f) f.Top) - InputData.Average(Function(f) f.Bottom) - InputData.Average(Function(f) f.Right) - InputData.Average(Function(f) f.Left) - InputData.Average(Function(f) f.OffCutHTop) - InputData.Average(Function(f) f.OffCutV)` but I do not know how to change into the for cycle between `f.Top, f.Bottom, f.Right, f.Left, f.OffCutH and f.OffCutV`

Comment: It seems as though you want arrays with 6 elements, given that you're talking about averaging 6 fields. If that's that case then the way you are creating your arrays, e.g. `Dim VariablesParameter(6) As VariablesParameterStructure`, is wrong. That creates an array with 7 elements. You specify the upper bound when you create an array in VB, which is 1 less than the length.

Comment: You also have some spelling errors in your code. You have "Analisys" instead of "Analysis" in two places and "Strucutre" instead of "Structure" in one place. You also must have `Option Strict Off` for that code to compile, which is bad. Why would you think that use a `Byte` in a `For` loop to index arrays was a good idea? Indexes are ALWAYS `Integers`. Turn `Option Strict On` for this project and make it the default in the VS options for all projects and help stop yourself writing bad code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```vb
Dim functions As Func(Of InputDataStructure, Single)() = {Function(ids) ids.Top,
                                                          Function(ids) ids.Bottom,
                                                          Function(ids) ids.Right,
                                                          Function(ids) ids.Left,
                                                          Function(ids) ids.OffCutH,
                                                          Function(ids) ids.OffCutV}

For i = 0 To VariablesGlobal.GetUpperBound(0)
    With VariablesGlobal(i)
        '...
        .Mean = InputData.Average(functions(i))
        '...
    End With
Next
```

By way of explanation, the `Function(f) f.ID` part of this line:

```vb
.Mean = InputData.Average(Function(f) f.ID)
```

is a lambda expression, i.e. a delegate for an anonymous method. The `Average` method that you're calling requires a delegate for a method that has a single argument of type `T`, where `T` matches the generic type of the `IEnumerable(Of T)` that you're calling it on, and returns a value of a numeric type, e.g. `Integer` or `Single`. In your case, you are calling `Average` on `InputData`, which implements `IEnumerable(Of InputDataStructure)`. Your lambda expression has a parameter of type `InputDataStructure` and returns an `Integer`, so it works with `Average`. The `Average` method invokes that delegate for every item in the list, gets all the numeric results and then divides that by the number of items in the list to get the average.

To make it clearer what is happening there, you could used a named method instead of a lambda expression. You could write this method:

```vb
Private Function GetID(f As InputDataStructure) As Integer
    Return f.ID
End Function
```

and then change your code to this:

```vb
.Mean = InputData.Average(AddressOf GetID)
```

Hopefully you can identify the parts of that named method that correspond to the lambda express and the parts that are inferred.

Now, you have a number of lines of code there that use the same lambda expression, e.g.

```vb
.Min = InputData.Min(Function(f) f.ID)
.Median = InputdataMedian(Function(f) f.ID)
.Q3 = InputData.ThirdQuartile(Function(f) f.ID)
```

for something so simple, it is customary to do it the way you have. You do have the option, though, of writing the lambda expression once, assigning it to a variable and then using that variable multiple times. You could do this:

```vb
Dim f As Func(Of InputDataStructure, Integer) = Function(ids) ids.ID
```

or this:

```vb
Dim f = Function(ids As InputDataStructure) ids.ID
```

to end up with the variable `f` referring to a delegate that takes an argument of type `InputDataStructure` and returns a value of type `Integer`. You can then use that variable where you previously used multiple lambda expressions:

```vb
.Min = InputData.Min(f)
.Median = InputdataMedian(f)
.Q3 = InputData.ThirdQuartile(f)
```

So, now that we determined that all you need is a delegate to a method that takes an argument of the correct type and returns the correct type, take another look at the code I posted. It first creates an array of six delegates, each of which takes an argument of type `InputDataStructure` and returns a value of type `Single`. You can then use an element of that array wherever such a delegate is expect.

That means that you can loop over that array and pass each delegate to all the extensions methods that expect such a delegate, including `Average`. If you get the delegate at index 0 then you get the delegate that returns the `Top` property value, so `Average` will get the average `Top` value. If you use index 5 then you get the delegate that returns the `OffCutV` property value, so `Average` will get the average `OffCutV` value. Etc.

For the record, I recommend using parameter names in lambdas that indicate the type. You used `f` but that's meaningless. The parameter type is `InputDataStructure` so `ids` is indicative of that.